Annotate django queryset based on related field attributes
Suppose you have this models structure in a django project
from django.db import models

class Object(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class ObjectEvent(models.Model):
    class EventTypes(models.IntegerChoices):
        CREATED = 1, "Created"
        SCHEDULED = 2, "Scheduled"
        COMPLETED = 3, "Completed"
        CANCELED = 4, "Canceled"

    event_type = models.IntegerField(choices=EventTypes.choices)
    object = models.ForeignKey(Object, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="events")

I now want to access the derived property ended which is defined as every object that have an event of type COMPLETED or CANCELED. I already did that with the @property decorator, but as I want to be able to filter using ended attribute. So I'm trying to implement this through the annotate queryset method.
class ObjectManager(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            qs = super().get_queryset()
            qs = qs.annotate(
                ended=models.Case(
                    models.When(
                        events__event_type__in=(
                            ObjectEvent.EventTypes.COMPLETED,
                            ObjectEvent.EventTypes.CANCELED,
                        ),
                        then=models.Value(True),
                    ),
                    default=models.Value(False),
                    output_field=models.BooleanField(
                        verbose_name="Object ended",
                    ),
                )
            )
            return qs
class Object(models.Model):
    objects = ObjectManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

fake_data.json
[
  { "model": "main.object", "pk": 1, "fields": { "name": "task1" } },
  { "model": "main.object", "pk": 2, "fields": { "name": "task2" } },
  { "model": "main.object", "pk": 3, "fields": { "name": "task3" } },
  { "model": "main.object", "pk": 4, "fields": { "name": "task4" } },
  {
    "model": "main.objectevent",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": { "event_type": 1, "object": 1 }
  },
  {
    "model": "main.objectevent",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": { "event_type": 2, "object": 1 }
  },
  {
    "model": "main.objectevent",
    "pk": 3,
    "fields": { "event_type": 4, "object": 1 }
  },
  {
    "model": "main.objectevent",
    "pk": 4,
    "fields": { "event_type": 1, "object": 2 }
  },
  {
    "model": "main.objectevent",
    "pk": 5,
    "fields": { "event_type": 1, "object": 3 }
  },
  {
    "model": "main.objectevent",
    "pk": 6,
    "fields": { "event_type": 2, "object": 3 }
  },
  {
    "model": "main.objectevent",
    "pk": 7,
    "fields": { "event_type": 3, "object": 3 }
  },
  {
    "model": "main.objectevent",
    "pk": 8,
    "fields": { "event_type": 1, "object": 4 }
  },
  {
    "model": "main.objectevent",
    "pk": 9,
    "fields": { "event_type": 2, "object": 4 }
  }
]

Now, trying with this fake data I have a strange result in manage.py shell
>>> ended_objects = Object.objects.filter(ended=True)
>>> ended_objects.count()
2 # this is fine
>>> not_ended_objects = Object.objects.filter(ended=False)
>>> not_ended_objects.count()
7 # why?
>>> not_ended_objects.distinct().count()
4 # Event using distinct doesn't resolve the problem

What am I missing?

If I understood correctly, an object is ended if it has a choice 3 or 4. There's only 2 objects with these choices in the json data you posted, pk 3 and pk 7. The other 7 doesn't have them. And of the 7 records that are not ended, there are 4 distinct objects, so I'm not sure what the problem is because that's exactly what your queries are returning.

Your annotation / filtering across relations needs a JOIN which causes some data duplication in the results. Check the linked duplicate.

You should try this for model.py

    from django.db import models
    from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Exists
        
    class ObjectManager(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            qs = super().get_queryset()
    
            completed_or_canceled_events = ObjectEvent.objects.filter(
                object=OuterRef('pk'),
                event_type__in=[
                    ObjectEvent.EventTypes.COMPLETED,
                    ObjectEvent.EventTypes.CANCELED
                ]
            )
    
            qs = qs.annotate(
                ended=Exists(completed_or_canceled_events)
            )
            return qs
    
    class Object(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        objects = ObjectManager()


